# jstree display document icon for some nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jstree that displays folders and documents and it works great but every node displays a Folder Icon. I have a type property in my json that determines whether it is a document or a folder(0 folder, 1 document) but I can't figure out how to switch it. 
this is how my code looks like.

I tried copying the code from [the demo page](http://www.jstree.com/demo/) but it's clearly not working

```
  $('#tree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'plugin': ['themes', 'types'],
                "types": {
                    "#": {
                        "valid_children": ["file"]
                    },
                    "file": {
                        "icon": "/Styles/file.png",
                        "valid_children": []
                    }
                },                   
                'check_callbacks': true,
                'themes': { 'stripes': true },
                'data': {
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'V2_DocTreeView.aspx/GetChildrenFor',
                    data: function (node) {
                        var group = 0;
                        if (node.id == "#")
                            group = getParameterByName("group");
                        else
                            group = node.id;
                        return '{id: "' + group + '"}';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the css file , and all images in the images folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my types definition and the plugin tag were inside the core as opposed to outside where it should be, furthermore the json (my model really) wasn't setting up the type property correctly. This is how the tree should look like

```
            $('#tree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'check_callback': true,
                'themes': { 'stripes': true },
                'data': {
                    type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'V2_DocTreeView.aspx/GetChildrenFor',
                    data: function (node) {
                        var group = 0;
                        if (node.id == "#")
                            group = getParameterByName("group");
                        else
                            group = node.id;
                        return '{id: "' + group + '"}';
                    }
                }
            },
            'types': {
                "default": {
                    "valid_children": ["default", "file"]
                },
                "file": {
                    "icon": "./Styles/file.png",
                    "valid_children": []
                }
            },
            'plugins': ['types']
        }
```